# Httpful: Unable to parse response as JSON

Tags: php, codeigniter, slim, httpful

I'm developing an web app using CodeIgniter and requesting data from a Slim REST Api. I'm having problems on my web app to get a response from a Httpful request. I use a base function to make all requests on my CodeIgniter frontend app, It goes like this:

```
function httpRequest($verb, $endpoint, $sentHeaders = null, $body = null)
{
    try {
        require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $context = & get_instance();

        $xUsuario = $context->session->usuario;

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'xAuthChaveApi' => $context->session->userdata('CLIENT_KEY'),
            'xAuthUsuarioID' => $xUsuario['id'],
            'xAuthUsuarioToken' => $xUsuario['sessao']['token']
        );

        if (isset($sentHeaders)) {
            $headers = array_merge($headers, $sentHeaders);
        }

        /*=========THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE=========*/
        $response = \Httpful\Request::{$verb}(API_URL . $endpoint)
            ->addHeaders($headers)
            ->body(json_encode($body))
            ->send();

        if ($response->code == 401) {
            encerrarSessao('Usuário não autorizado! Verifique os dados das suas credenciais e tente novamente');
        }

        return json_decode(json_encode($response->body), true);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        show_error('O seguinte erro ocorreu ao fazer requisição aos servidores: ' . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I've tested with both the Web App and the API hosted on my localhost, the App on my localhost and the API on the Hostgator's server and It works like a charm. But when both the App and the Api are hosted on the online server is when I get the error. Funny thing is that the error only occurs on this particular endpoint, I have no problems at all with the others either local or online. I can even call this endpoint on the server with postman and It works fine.

This is the endpoint code I have on the API:

```
public static function listarImportacao(Request $request, Response $response) {
        try {
            $dataInicial = $request->getHeader('dataInicial')[0];
            $dataFinal = $request->getHeader('dataFinal')[0];

            if(!isset($dataInicial) && !isset($dataFinal)) {
                $dataInicial = date('Y-m-d');
                $dataFinal = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));
            }

            $partidas = Partida::whereBetween(
                'dataHora',
                array($dataInicial, $dataFinal)
            )
            ->with(array('liga.pais', 'timeCasa', 'timeFora'))
            ->where('flagDisponivel', '!=', '1')
            ->where('cotacao', '!=', 'null')
            ->whereRaw('(dataHora >= (now() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))')
            ->get();

            $meta = Helper::metaArray(Enum::SUCS_STS, Enum::SELECTED);

            $partidas = Helper::formatarPartidas($partidas);

            return $response->withCustomJson($meta, $partidas);

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $meta = Helper::metaArray(Enum::ERR_STS, $ex, 400);

            return $response->withCustomJson($meta);
        }
    }
```

This is the controller function that makes the request:

```
public function importacao() {
        try {
            $post = $this->input->post();

            if(isset($post['dataInicial']) && isset($post['dataFinal'])) {
                $dataInicial = dataAmericana($post['dataInicial']);
                $dataFinal = dataAmericana($post['dataFinal']);

                setFlashData($post['dataInicial'], 'dataInicial');
                setFlashData($post['dataFinal'], 'dataFinal');
            } else {
                $dataInicial = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));
                $dataFinal = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));
            }

            $headers = array(
                'dataInicial' => $dataInicial,
                'dataFinal' => $dataFinal
            );

            $partidas = httpRequest('GET', Endpoint::listaImportacao, $headers);

            //var_dump($partidas['data']); die();

            $dados = array(
                'titulo' => 'Importação de Partidas',
                'nomeView' => 'partida/importacao',
                'partidas' => isset($partidas['data']) ? $partidas['data'] : null
            );

            $this->load->view('menus/main', $dados);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            show_error('O seguinte erro ocorreu ao fazer requisição aos servidores: ' . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the content the API returns? (From Postman for example)

Also what is the Accept header you set in Postman? Does it differ from your serverside request?

Comment: Also `json_decode(json_encode($response->body), true)` looks weird. Does it not just cast the content from stdClass to array in case it is a stdClass? I think `return is_object($response->body) ? (array)$response->body : $response->body` might be faster for that.

Comment: Of course, here it is http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a6681c1cccf0f5d2f917c9133bf597f2

Comment: I've tried to cast the object but It doesn't work. I don't know why but It doens't become an array.

Comment: Postman data: https://i.imgur.com/OFdrvPn.png

var_dump of $headers in httRequest function: https://i.imgur.com/jv8ua1i.png

Comment: You are using GET in postman, but POST on the server. Do you still get a valid result if you use POST in Postman instead?

Comment: I'm also using GET on the server. If I use post I get a "Method not allowed" error message from the API.

Comment: Did you debug the parameters `$verb` and `$body`? Are you sure it is `'get'`? Is `$body` maybe a curl connection?

Comment: Yes, $verb is 'GET' and the $body is NULL as It should be. As you can see here: https://i.imgur.com/lUSpImG.png

Comment: What is strange is that It works great on localhost and It also works when I use Postman. I have no idea what might cause this behaviour only when the frontend app is on the server.

Comment: Since the error is `Unable to parse response as JSON` just do the `json_encode` part before you build the request and surround it with `try/catch`. If it throws an error set `$body` to `NULL` See if it works then. `\Httpful\Request` does not `json_encode` itself. If you edited \Httpful\Request look for `json_encode` in there.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error also *Unable to parse response as JSON* and I was sure the returned json was ok.
After a long search there was also a php error in the output for a missing variable. That was corrupting the correct json output.
So check for php related errors.